# JS - Программно назначить обработчик клика на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Господа, 
я заранее извиняюсь, что задаю довольно простой вопрос, но сам я за полночи разоброаться не смог.
У меян есть "одностраничное приложение". Весь код - это js, которым я вставляю в страницу нужные эементы. Чекбоксики. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
// вначале есть массив исходных данных resp.data
let elem = document.getElementById('div_for_checkboxes');

// добавляем в него checkbox'ы
for (var i=0; i<=resp.data.length-1; i++) {
    var item = resp.data[i]; // item - это json - структура вида {
                                                        //    "id": 42,
                                                        //    "name": "О странствующих и путешествующих"
                                                        //   }
    // программно создаю чекбокс
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.id = item["id"];
    checkbox.value = item["id"];
    checkbox.onclick = function(){ alert('??'); };

    // программно создаю label
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.htmlFor = item["id"];
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item["name"]));

    // добавляю  то и другое в предназначенный для этого div
    elem.appendChild(checkbox);
    elem.appendChild(label);
    elem.innerHTML += ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
};
```

Так, как написано в коде -

```
checkbox.onclick = function(){ alert('??'); };
```

- событие не добавляется.

Пробовал еще и так:

```
elem.innerHTML += ' onclick=name_of_js_function();';
```

- в результате это текст просто дописывается на страницу

Пробовал еще так:

```
checkbox.innerHTML += ' onclick="alert(\'!!!\');"';
```

- тоже не работает.

Не могу понять, как ему подсунуть этот обработчик события.
Спасибо заранее за советы!

Comment: checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {...});

Comment: Спасибо за светлую идею. Я поппробовал - написав checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('!!!?'); }); К сожалению, этот обработчик так же не вызывается. Не могу понять, в чем проблема...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парни, большое спасибо, что Вы меня вразумляли и давали полезные советы.

Напомню еще раз, что мне нужно к каждому чекбоксу привязать обработчик события, и в этом обработчике я должен понимать, по какому чекбоксу кликнули.

К сожалению, 1) все методы "дописывания события onclick прямо в HTML" при динамическом создании элемента (имеются в виду `elem.innerHTML +=...` и метод `insertAdjacentHTML`) обладают какими то глубинными недостатками, из за которых обработчик события не вызывается.

2) При добавлении обработчика события методом `.addEventListener`

```
var ch = document.getElementById(tr["id"]);
ch.addEventListener( "click", ()=>cb_tr_click(tr["id"]) );
```

итспользуются анонимные функции. А они обладают свойством: прии вызове они вызываются с текущим значением аргумента. Ну, то есть, в тот момент, когда работает цикл, в котором создаются чекбоксы - их ID известен, но в это тмомнет функция не вызывается. А когад происходит клик - то этот ID вообще не имеет смысла, потому что цикл отработал и переменная вышла из области видимости - короче, обработчик всегда вызывался с нулдевым аргументом.

Последний совет мне дал товарищ "в оффлайне", и его решение реально работает:

```
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.id = tr["id"];
        checkbox.value = tr["id"];
        checkbox.setAttribute("onclick","alert('"+tr["id"]+"');");
```

Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Лучше не делать это через `setAttribute`, для этого есть `addEventListener` или еще лучше - это сам `element.onclick`. на счет установки аттрибута это может в некоторых браузерах не работать в должном образе.

Comment: Для всех динамически создаваемых элементов существует [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation). Оно оч хорошо реализовано в jQuery, а в JS приходится немного повозиться.

Comment: я очень извиняюсь, я пробовал решить задачу через addEventListener. Но, видно, руки кривоваты пока :-). Вот я повесил обработчик. На все чекбоксы. Одитн обработчик. Кликнули по чекбоксу. Как мне в обработчике узнать, по какому из чекбоксов кликнули? - ой, сходил по ссылке, прочитал про event.target; - и, кажется, начал понимать,к ак это делать...

Answer (score 3):

Сотрите строку кода `elem.innerHTML += ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'`. Не уверен в том, зачем она, но она что-то перезаписывает в дочерних элементах элемента с id `'div_for_checkboxes'`. Возможно, вместо elem.innerHTML, вам нужно использовать метод [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
// вначале есть массив исходных данных resp.data
let elem = document.getElementById('div_for_checkboxes');
let resp = {};
resp.data = [{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "О странствующих и путешествующих"
}]

// добавляем в него checkbox'ы
for (var i = 0; i <= resp.data.length - 1; i++) {
  var item = resp.data[i]; // item - это json - структура вида {
  //    "id": 42,
  //    "name": "О странствующих и путешествующих"
  //   }
  // программно создаю чекбокс
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.id = item["id"];
  checkbox.value = item["id"];
  checkbox.onclick = function() {

    alert('??');
  };

  // программно создаю label
  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = item["id"];
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item["name"]));

  // добавляю  то и другое в предназначенный для этого div
  elem.appendChild(checkbox);
  elem.appendChild(label);
  
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // elem.innerHTML += ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
};
```

```html
<div id="div_for_checkboxes">
```

Comment: Круто!!! Вот реально - умом этого понять нельзя, это можно только применить как магию!!!

Comment: Конечно, без этой строки можно обойтись, надо просто правильный CSS класс написать для чекбокса, чтобы он был отделен от другого чекбокса. Но это вызывает следующйи вопрос - как ему, собаке, пприсвоить CSS класс?

Comment: @S.H. css классы с помощью js присваиваются довольно легко `elem.classlist.add('className')`. Больше [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Большое спасибо, и спасибо за подсказу про insertAdjacentHTML. Я, вообще, стараюсь вникнуть в тему, но иногда много всего наваливается и приходится учиться в процессе :-)

Comment: @S.H. ну просто любое присваивание innerHTML / textContent полностью обновляет все внутренности. Даже если там уже было 10 тыс. строчек, а вы добавили всего один символ. Соответственно, и все повешанные обработчики пропадают. А insertAdjacentHTML вставляет новый кусок, не трогая остальные.